# Detect "#VALUE!" cells in EPPLUS C#

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

I was wondering if there is anyway to detect cells with invalid references where they appear as #VALUE! in the excel sheet. I don't want to detect empty or null cells, but only specifically when they appear as #VALUE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (cell.Value is OfficeOpenXml.ExcelErrorValue) { DoSomething(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EEPlus, this is easy: A cell's `Value` property is returned as an object of type `OfficeOpenXml.ExcelErrorValue`.